# java8 stream grouping aggregate

Tags: sum, java-8, grouping, java-stream

Given a java class `Something`

```
class Something {
     String parent;
     String parentName;
     String child;
     Date at;
     int noThings;

     Something(String parent, String parentName, String child, Date at, int noThings) {
          this.parent = parent;
          this.parentName = parentName;
          this.child = child;
          this.at = at;
          this.noThings = noThings;
      }

      String getParent() { return parent; }
      String getChild() { return child; }
      int getNoThings() { return noThings; }
}
```

I have a list of something objects,

```
List<Something> hrlySomethings = Arrays.asList(
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child1", new Date("01-May-2015 10:00:00"), 4),
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child1", new Date("01-May-2015 12:00:00"), 2),
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child1", new Date("01-May-2015 17:00:00"), 8),
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child2", new Date("01-May-2015 07:00:00"), 12),
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child2", new Date("01-May-2015 17:00:00"), 14),
    new Something("parent2", "pname2", "child3", new Date("01-May-2015 11:00:00"), 3),
    new Something("parent2", "pname2", "child3", new Date("01-May-2015 16:00:00"), 2));
```

I want to group the objects by parent and children and then find the total/sum of the "noThings" field for the last 24 hours.

```
List<Something> dailySomethings = Arrays.asList(
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child1", new Date("01-May-2015 00:00:00"), 14),
    new Something("parent1", "pname1", "child2", new Date("01-May-2015 00:00:00"), 26),
    new Something("parent2", "pname2", "child3", new Date("01-May-2015 00:00:00"), 5))
```

I'm trying to use the streams to do this

I can figure out how to use the grouping to get a map of maps, and the total

```
    Map<String,Map<String,IntSummaryStatistics>> daily =
        hrlySomethings.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Something ::getParent, 
    Collectors.groupingBy(ClientCollectionsReceived::getChild,
    Collectors.summarizingInt(ClientCollectionsReceived::getNoThings))));
```

I can figure out how to get a distinct list based on parent and child,

```
    Date startHour = "01-May-2015 00:00:00";
    int totalNoThings = 0; // don't know how to put sum in here
    List<Something> newList 
      = hrlySomethings.stream()
            .map((Something other) -> {
                    return new Something(other.getParent(),
                    other.getChild(), startHour, totalNoThings);
                })
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I don't know how to combine the two to get the distinct list, with the totals.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I assume that you are using `java.util.Date` (though I'd advise you to move to new `java.time` API). Second, I assume that `Something` class has also properly implemented `equals` and `hashCode`. Also more getters are necessary:

```
String getParentName() { return parentName; }
Date getAt() { return at; }
```

Under these assumptions your task can be solved like this:

```
List<Something> dailySomethings = hrlySomethings.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        smth -> new Something(smth.getParent(), 
                              smth.getParentName(), 
                              smth.getChild(), 
                              new Date(smth.getAt().getYear(),
                                       smth.getAt().getMonth(), 
                                       smth.getAt().getDate()), 
                              0),
        Collectors.summingInt(Something::getNoThings)
    )).entrySet().stream()
                 .map(entry -> new Something(entry.getKey().getParent(),
                                             entry.getKey().getParentName(), 
                                             entry.getKey().getChild(), 
                                             entry.getKey().getAt(), 
                                             entry.getValue()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We use `groupingBy` only once, but create a suitable grouping key, which is the `Something` with `parent`, `parentName` and `child` set to the original, `at` changed to the day beginning and `noThings` set to zero. This way you group what you want. If you need only total sums, then `summarizingInt` is unnecessary, `summingInt` is enough. After that we transform the resulting map to the list creating new `Something` objects where `noThings` is filled from the map values and the rest is filled from the keys.